# IndexError at /detectWithWebcam list index out of range

Tags: python, django, image-processing, face-recognition, indexoutofrangeexception

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/detectWithWebcam

Django Version: 2.2
Python Version: 3.9.7
Installed Applications:

```
['main',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Error:

```
    Traceback:
    
    File "C:\Users\INTROVERTED\Downloads\Compressed\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
      34.             response = get_response(request)
    
    File "C:\Users\INTROVERTED\Downloads\Compressed\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
    
    File "C:\Users\INTROVERTED\Downloads\Compressed\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    
    File "C:\Users\INTROVERTED\Downloads\Compressed\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\main\views.py" in detectWithWebcam
      303.         encodings[i]=face_recognition.face_encodings(images[i])[0]
    
    Exception Type: IndexError at /detectWithWebcam
    Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

So Indexerror means that the specified index not exist in the list.
Following Code would throw a indexerror:

```py
pylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(pylist[5])
```

This is because python start counting at 0 so to access number 5 you would need to index by 4.

In your particular case you should try to print out the values without indexing to see, which pice of code cause the indexerror.